# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004

Tags: swift, xcode

i am a beginner and im encountering problem while deploying my app on my phone. The application is working fine on the simulator but when i run on my phone and try to send in the registration form on my phone, i got the error below

> FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x174244da0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost/Syafiqah_153046u/register.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost/Syafiqah_153046u/register.php, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}

Below is my source code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fullname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phone: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelMessage: UILabel!

    @IBAction func Register(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let URL_USER_REGISTER = "http://localhost/FYP/register.php"

        let parameters: Parameters=[

            "username":username.text!,

            "password":password.text!,

            "email":email.text!,

            "fullname":fullname.text!,

            "phone":phone.text!

        ]

        //Sending http post request

        Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON

            {
                response in

                //printing response

                print(response)



                //getting the json value from the server

                if let result = response.result.value

                {

                    //converting it as NSDictionary

                    let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

                    //displaying the message in label

                    self.labelMessage.text = jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as! String?

                }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
   }
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: "Could not connect to the server." Of course: `http://localhost/FYP/register.php` ... "localhost" ... *local*

Comment: Try local IP address instead of localhost..hope will help you

Comment: omg yes it worked!! Thank you so much @Jaydeep

Comment: thank you for making me realise my silly mistake!! @EricAya

Comment: @nrsyaf You're welcome. :)

Comment: In addition to using the actual IP and Port I also had to go to info.plist and under App Transport Security options, enable `allows arbitrary loads` and enable `allows local networking`

Answer (score 1):

Accessing localhost from the iPhone will simply do a loopback / try to connect to itself (If it supports that?).

What you need to do is find the IP of your desktop machine (e.g. If Windows, go to the Command Prompt and type `ipconfig` or go to Network and Sharing Centre and look up connection status.

Comment: In my case even with ip of my mac does not work, because my iphone use 4G because doesnt exists wifi on the company :(